# Trying to add a WhatsApp Business API test number to a group

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I've created a Meta app and got a Whatsapp test number. I can write to it and it is send to the webhook fine. But I'd like to add that number to a group so others can send messages to it as well, without necessarily needing to add that weird number.

[image]

When trying to do so it says that Business number can't be added to a group.

Is there something I can do? Am I forced to add my own number to the app and convert it to a Business number?

I'd rather not, I'd like to keep mine personal

Answer (score 0):

It's listed nowhere, but unfortunately, Phonenumber accounts that are registered on the WhatsApp Business API are blocked from being added to groups. It's not supported by Meta.

Comment: So if I were to make my personal number into a Business number and add it to the API, it would get kicked from all groups and lose the ability to get into them?

That's seems weird, given lots of businesses use their Business numbers to manage groups. Are you sure of that? Or are we talking different things?

Comment: That's correct. A number that connects to the Cloud Meta API to use the Business API does not have the ability to interact with WA groups. If you move your number to this status, it will not be removed from the group, but you will not be able to interact with the group in any way. 
If any companies manage groups, they do it either manually or through unofficial solutions